# Print pipe content to screen

Tags: c, pipe, execl

I am using the `execlp()` to execute commands on child process and save into a pipe to be read by parent as such for example

```
int pipefd[2];
if (pipe(pipefd)) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(127);
}
if(!fork()){
    close(pipefd[0]);
    dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
} else {
    close(pipefd[1]);
    dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    execlp("wc", "wc", NULL);
}
```

In some cases, parent doesn't have to execute anything, but rather just print out content of the pipe on the screen, how can I print pipe on screen (possibly without storing into a variable due to unknown output size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I print [the content of the] pipe on [the] screen

`read()` from the pipe byte by byte and `printf("%d\n", byte);` it until the pipe is empty, that is until `read()` returned `0`.

If you can asure it's just text coming through the pipe don't print the byte as `int` (one per line as shown above) but as `char` in a row using `printf("%c", byte);`